# Extract diagonal of a matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std, stdvector

I am exercising using the std of C++ for school and I would like to find a way to extract the diagonal of a matrix with std::copy. This is what I came out with but it is giving me a segmentation fault error. What am I doing wrong? Is there maybe a more C++ way to do this without using for loops?
Thank you

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm> 
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator> 

int main () {

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec {{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{1,6,7} ;
    std::vector<int> vec1{0,0,0} ; 
    std::copy ( &vec[0][0], &vec[2][2], &vec1[0] ) ;

}
```

Comment: assuming that the data in `vec` is stored like a corresponding array (i.e. `int vec[3][3]`, and this isn't actually guaranteed IIRC)) then your copying would copy all nine elements of `vec` into the three-element vector `vec1`.

Comment: And what's wrong with a simple `for` loop to do what you need?

Comment: Here are some questions to get you on track to finding the solution yourself: What does `&vec[0][0]` and `&vec[2][2]` evaluate to? I mean the type, not the value. Based on that type, what do you think `copy()` does with it? Can you translate `copy()` into a loop? What would it look like? What would a loop to extract the diagonal look like?

Comment: Well, you could write a custom iterator to traverse the matrix along the diagonal and feed   a couple of those (the begin and end) to `std::copy`, but I'm quite confident this is *not* what you are supposed to do here, not to mention it would be a task orders of magnitudes more complex than a single loop.

Comment: @Some programmer dude
Nothing wrong with a simple for loop, but I would like to learn a bit of STL. I often see answers with one line of code using some exotic algorithm from STL instead of for loops and I thought that I could do something like that, but probably  this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting a segmentation fault is because of the way you're using copy, which you're giving invalid parameters. There's not really a way to iterate through a 2D array or vector diagonally (although if you are using a 2D array (not a vector), you can give it a start and end point diagonal from one another, but it would just copy everything in between, not just the diagonals).

I would recommend just using a for loop, there's nothing wrong with that. (Even if there is some convoluted way to get copy to work, a for loop is plenty clear and fast enough already).

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm> 
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator> 

int main () {

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec {{1,2,3},{3,4,5},{1,6,7}} ;
    // std::vector<int> vec1{0,0,0} ; 
    // std::copy ( &vec[0][0], &vec[2][2], &vec1[0] ) ;

    std::vector<int> diagonal;
    for(uint i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
        diagonal.push_back(vec[i][i]);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a standard *array*, where all elements of the array are stored *contiguously*.  Instead, you have an *edge-vector array* (wikipedia calls this an [Iliffe vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliffe_vector) though I've never heard anyone actually call it that myself).  Consequently, your indexing method has to take that into account.  And as pointed out (in other answers and comments), there's no way to do that with normal *iterators* which work only within a *single container*.

(An edge vector array is a *jagged array* with the constraint that all the vectors pointed to are the same length.)
[image: Jagged array, image from Wikipedia]

You can index it as a "unit" with a *segmented iterator* (as described in ["Segmented Iterators and Hierarchical Algorithms" (Austern) (pdf)](http://lafstern.org/matt/segmented.pdf) if you wish.  But that's a lot of work to go through for most simple use cases, like the one you describe, where a simple for-loop will do just fine (and be easier to understand and debug).